# Is it mandatory to write Contract, Provider and DbHelper in android to access remote database?

Tags: java, android, performance, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am learning Android programming from Udacity android Intermediate. https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853/l-3599339441/m-3659838854  Here they have mentioned about writing a Contract, a Provider and DbHelper to access a database. Questions
1) Is this (using contract, provider and db helper) the correct practice to access database?
2) Should I do this way for executing one simple select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not mandatory. However, it would be good to use the 3 components as they make it much easier to maintain the database. Here's some specific reasons regarding each component:

- Data Contract: helps you nicely summarize the tables. This proves to be much important when the application grows and the number of tables increases.
- Content Provider: you would need the Content Provider if you use cursor loader to load data. Cursor loader is a recommended way to load data from sqlite, as it runs in the background and will not interfere with the UI. Otherwise, a simple query of large amount of data can make the UI laggy. Also, if you allow other applications to access your application's database, Content Provider also serves as an abstraction, so that other applications can query your database without knowing how it is structured.
- Open Helper: to manage opening and upgrading the database. This is mainly used with ContentProvider. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html):

> This class makes it easy for ContentProvider implementations to defer opening and upgrading the database until first use, to avoid blocking application startup with long-running database upgrades.